# Check whether an integer (or all elements of a list of integers) be prime

Tags: haskell, recursion, primes

I'm doing a simple Haskell function using recursion. At the moment, this seems to work but, if I enter `2`, it actually comes up as false, which is irritating. I don't think the code is as good as it could be, so, if you have any advice there, that'd be cool too!

I'm pretty new to this language!

EDIT: Ok, so I understand what a prime number is.

For example, I want to be able to check 2, 3, 5, 7, etc and have `isPrime` return `true`. And of course if I run the function using 1, 4, 6, 8 etc then it will return `false`.

So, my thinking is that in pseudo code I would need to do as follows:

```
num = 2 -> return true
num > 2 && num = even -> return false
```

After that, I'm struggling to write it down in any working code so the code below is my work in process, but I really suck with Haskell so I'm going nowhere at the minute.

```
module Recursion where

isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime x = if x > 2 then ((x `mod` (x-1)) /= 0) && not (isPrime (x-1)) else False
```

Comment: the problem is not your code or your understanding of Haskell - the problem is the definition of your `prime` numbers - you are saying here: a number is prime if it's bigger than 2, is not divisible by it's predecessor and it's predecessor is not prime - all of which is wrong

Comment: maybe you can add what you did try to say - when should a number be prime?

Comment: I understand what a prime number is, I'm just struggling to put it down into code!

Comment: then please add the desired definition to your question and we can answer in code

Comment: ok better - but still not every odd number is prime - for example 15 is not - what is the definition you know from school?

Comment: @CarstenKönig I added a little bit more information, I'll try my best to help you as I appreciate your help

Comment: @CarstenKönig Yep, I understand that, which is why I'm struggling to transfer my Maths into code. Of course from school...a prime number is one which is natural and positive, which is only divisible by 1 and itself

Comment: You still haven't said what (you think) a prime number is, just that you know what they are. Please write down (in math and words, not Haskell) your definition of a prime number. *Then* think about how you would go about checking whether a number is prime yourself (with a pen and paper). Only then should you worry about translating that into Haskell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok,

let's do this step by step:

In math a (natural) number `n` is prime if it has exactly 2 divisors: 1 and itself (mind 1 is not a prime).

So let's first get all of the divisors of a number:

```
divisors :: Integer -> [Integer]
divisors n = [ d | d <- [1..n], n `mod` d == 0 ]
```

then get the count of them:

```
divisorCount :: Integer -> Int
divisorCount = length . divisors
```

and voila we have the most naive implementation using just the definition:

```
isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime n = divisorCount n == 2
```

now of course there can be quite some impprovements:

- instead check that there is no divisor `> 1` and `< n`
- you don't have to check all divisors up to `n-1`, it's enough to check to the squareroot of n
- ...

Ok just to give a bit more performant version and make @Jubobs happy ;) here is an alternative:

```
isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime n
  | n <= 1 = False
  | otherwise = not . any divides $ [2..sqrtN]
  where divides d = n `mod` d == 0
        sqrtN = floor . sqrt $ fromIntegral n
```

This one will check that there is no divisor between `2` and the squareroot of the number

### complete code:

using quickcheck to make sure the two definitions are ok:

```
module Prime where

import Test.QuickCheck

divisors :: Integer -> [Integer]
divisors n = [ d | d <- [1..n], n `mod` d == 0 ]

divisorCount :: Integer -> Int
divisorCount = length . divisors

isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime n
  | n <= 1 = False
  | otherwise = not . any divides $ [2..sqrtN]
  where divides d = n `mod` d == 0
        sqrtN = floor . sqrt $ fromIntegral n

isPrime' :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime' n = divisorCount n == 2

main :: IO()
main = quickCheck (\n -> isPrime' n == isPrime n)
```

### !!warning!!

I just saw (had something in the back of my mind), that the way I did `sqrtN` [**is not the best way to do it**](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Generic_number_type#squareRoot) - sorry for that. I think for the examples with small numbers here it will be no problem, but maybe you really want to use something like this (right from the link):

```
(^!) :: Num a => a -> Int -> a
(^!) x n = x^n

squareRoot :: Integer -> Integer
squareRoot 0 = 0
squareRoot 1 = 1
squareRoot n =
   let twopows = iterate (^!2) 2
       (lowerRoot, lowerN) =
          last $ takeWhile ((n>=) . snd) $ zip (1:twopows) twopows
       newtonStep x = div (x + div n x) 2
       iters = iterate newtonStep (squareRoot (div n lowerN) * lowerRoot)
       isRoot r  =  r^!2 <= n && n < (r+1)^!2
   in  head $ dropWhile (not . isRoot) iters
```

but this seems a bit heavy for the question on hand so I just remark it here.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a go and let you know if I run into any problems

Comment: @Jubobs yep it isn't and it don't claim to be just as the remarks at the end will tell you - BUT it's IMHO most close to what you find on primes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number) and very easy to implement - I don't think the OP needs a efficiency here - he needs understanding

Comment: @CarstenKönig Yes, but IMHO, it would be preferable to direct the OP towards a solution that uses lazy evaluation (more specifically, here, short-circuit evaluation of Booleans).

Comment: I don't need efficiency that's for sure, I'm just trying to get to grips with recursion in Haskell.

Comment: @CarstenKönig would be run as standalone code right? Just tested the previous one and I noticed the flaws you were talking about so I'll give this a look. Thanks by the way!

Comment: @germainelol oh sorry - you need a recursive version? The only recursive one I can think of right now is the sieve: http://en.literateprograms.org/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes_(Haskell) - but I'd rather not start this discussion

Comment: Yeah, I should be using recursion, first I'm just trying to get a simple function working though. But yes I'll be using recursion afterwards

Comment: @germainelol there are a lot of different implementations here: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers

Comment: @CarstenKönig Gah, how would you get the second code running as a standalone .hs file? I've used the sieve method before in Java and had no problems but I'm not getting much luck running/using Haskell just yet

Comment: @CarstenKönig Now I'm happy :)

Comment: @germainlol - I'll give you a complete programm (that checks if the two are the same as an addon ;) )

Comment: @CarstenKönig Thanks an awful lot, I appreciate your help

Comment: Can you recommend anything to change that second function into a recursive function? Or would it be better to start from scratch with a sieve function? I really don't like the Haskell syntax :P

Comment: @germainelol I see no handle to make the simple test into a recursive function (and to be honest I don't see why it has to be either) - so yeah probably it's sieve then (but as I said: there are *huge* debates about what are *real* implementations in Haskell and I don't wanna start this kind of discussion here :D)

Comment: btw @Jubobs had a version using recursion - but that was just doing, what `any` is doing here - maybe he'll want to resurrect if it helps you?

Comment: thanks @CarstenKönig could you explain what exactly divisorCount does by the way? I understand most of the rest

Comment: @germainelol - this is not to complicated: it just counts the number of divisors (for example 15 should have 4: [1,3,5,15] and it just takes the length of that list - you can expand the definition to `divisorCount n = length (divisors n)`

Comment: Why don't you generate until the number² is larger than the limit? `takeWhile (\x -> x*x <= n) [1..]`

Comment: @JohannesKuhn that would work as well but not as efficient as the snippet I copied there - I could add this but I don't think it would really add more to the answer as the OP seems to be content - but thank you for your feedback!

Comment: @CarstenKönig You don't have to use any square root function at all; see my approach, for instance.

Comment: @Jubobs I think it's fine that we have different answers here - and I already upvoted yours ... so I see no need to change this answer any more

Comment: @CarstenKönig Ok, fair enough. I wasn't begging for an upvote :)

Comment: @Jubobs I did not think you did ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here are two facts about prime numbers.

1. The first prime number is 2.
2. An integer larger than 2 is prime iff it's not divisible by any prime number up to its square root.

This knowledge should naturally lead you to something like the following approach:

```hs
-- primes : the infinite list of prime numbers
primes :: [Integer]
primes = 2 : filter isPrime [3,5..]

-- isPrime n : is positive integer 'n' a prime number?
isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime n
    | n < 2     = False
    | otherwise = all (\p -> n `mod` p /= 0) (primesPrefix n)
    where primesPrefix n = takeWhile (\p -> p * p <= n) primes
```

As a bonus, here is a function to test whether all items of a list of integers be prime numbers.

```hs
-- arePrimes ns : are all integers in list 'ns' prime numbers?
arePrimes :: [Integer] -> Bool
arePrimes = all isPrime
```

Some examples in `ghci`:

```
ghci> isPrime 3
True
ghci> isPrime 99
False
ghci> arePrimes [2,3,7]
True
ghci> arePrimes [2,3,4,7]
False
```

Comment: Would you care to comment some of the code? I'm about 90% understanding the above code from his answer! Apologies!

Comment: Ok, so first we check if n <2 .... then we apply the primeHelper to (n-1) right? and `d` becomes `n-1`?

Comment: before your last edit the prefix of `primes` remained in memory just as well. you were just checking for equality (and `takewhile` just serve as a search limit), now you add the `mod` calculations, though they are short-circuiting. If you wanted to speed up the search for membership, you could trade list for a tree, for a logarithmic advantage (search on a tree is *O(log n)*). Though the practicality of keeping the tree of primes in memory is questionable.

Comment: @WillNess Sorry. I had missed your comment, for some reason. Can you elaborate on how you would store primes in a tree?

Comment: `data Tree = Prime Int | Node Tree Tree` ; `primes_tree = `[`foldi `](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#Tree-like_folds) `Node undefined $ map Prime primes` or something. But not exactly so; will need to label Nodes too, with leftmost leaf, to facilitate searching.

Comment: @WillNess Thanks for that. I'm very new to Haskell, and only just starting to fool around with user-defined data types.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a recursive formulation from the "2 divisors" variant by step-wise [refinement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refinement_%28computing%29):

```
isPrime n 
    = 2 == length  [ d | d <- [1..n], rem n d == 0 ]
    = n > 1 && null [ d | d <- [2..n-1], rem n d == 0 ]
    = n > 1 && and [ rem n d > 0 | d <- takeWhile ((<= n).(^2)) [2..] ]
    = n > 1 && g 2
       where
         g d = d^2 > n || (rem n d > 0 && g (d+1))
    = n == 2 || (n > 2 && rem n 2 > 0 && g 3)
       where
         g d = d^2 > n || (rem n d > 0 && g (d+2))
```

And that's your recursive function. Convince yourself of each step's validity.

Of course after we've checked the division by 2, there's no need to try dividing by 4,6,8, etc.; that's the reason for the last transformation, to check by odds only. But really we need to check the divisibility by *primes* only.