# Finding primes using Sieve of Eratosthenes not working - Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes, sieve

Here is the code I am trying to use: This should generate all primes up to 100

```
sieve_primes = [x | x<-[2..100], y<-[2..50], z <-[2..25], (x*z) `mod` y /= 0]
```

Comment: If you define `primes` to be the infinite list of prime numbers (as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324275/check-whether-an-integer-or-all-elements-of-a-list-of-integers-be-prime/26324612#26324612)), then the solution to your problem is as simple as `take 100 primes`.

Comment: Jubobs: That would yield the first 100 primes. To get all primes up to 100, use `takeWhile (<= 100) primes`.

Comment: @hammar Oops, you're right. Sorry, I misread the question.

Comment: @user3237465 when I import the package and run `main = print Prime`, I get an error `Not in scope: data constructor: "Prime"`

Comment: @John Doe, what is that dollar for? Use the library like this: `main = print $ takeWhile (< 100) primes`.

Comment: My mistake, I used a capital on the P. Embarrassing. Thanks for the help!. Really appreciate it

Comment: @user3237465 the package you recommend to use appears to be performing *significantly* worse than the faster (likewise immutable) functions from the wiki page (like 6.1 and 3.10,  when compiled of course). Mutable arrays code in it is much faster and is still far from being optimized; the [arithmoi package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.4.1.1/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Primes-Sieve.html) should probably be used for that.

Comment: it was wrong to edit out the intent of the OP; I rolled back my edit.

Comment: The Sieve of Eratosthenes does not use the modulus to detect multiples, it uses addition (or multiplication) to generate them.

Comment: @Will Ness, yep, you are right. I've been using this package for solving Euler problems for a year, but even 6.1 in the wiki is much better. I deleted my comment. OP, sorry for confusing.

Comment: @molbdnilo you're right, but, the code shown doesn't work anyway - the intent of the OP was indeed the SoE of sorts, generating the possible multiples (as I hope is seen more clearly in my now updated answer).

Comment: @user3237465 pity you've removed it, now our comments are orphaned (mine and yours)...  the wiki page we both refer to is http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers, and the other package is [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/primes-0.2.1.0/docs/Data-Numbers-Primes.html). --- BTW 6.1  is the fastest of the immutable codes there, even without the proper wheel support. :) --- [arithmoi](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.4.1.1/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Primes-Sieve.html) is *very* fast.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prime Sieve in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768958/prime-sieve-in-haskell)

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
isPrime n = length [x | x<-[2..n], n `mod` x == 0] == 1
```

computes *all* the factors just to count them. You don't need to count them: as soon as the second factor is found you can stop your search without checking for further ones.

So, either replace `length ... == 1` with a custom predicate, or `take 2` elements from the list comprehension before checking its length.

Comment: Sorry, my main issue was the first code I put up above. I had the second one working but it was too slow. Made a mistake typing it out was all. I think I'll delete that code. Any idea why the 1st piece of code isn't working? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JohnDoe The first will generate all the `x`s such that __there exist__ `y,z` satisfying the divisor requirement. For instance, `x=6` will be in that list because if we take `y=7, z=1` we get `6*1 mod 7 == 6 /= 0`. This amounts to saying that 7 is not a divisor of 6, hence 6 is prime.

Answer (score 0):

What you had in mind was probably

```
Prelude> [x| x<-[2..100], not $ elem x [y*z| y<-[2..50], z<-[2..25]]]
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97]
```

This is very slow. At least we can rearrange the pieces,

```
Prelude> [x| let sieve=[y*z| y<-[2..50], z<-[2..25]], 
             x<-[2..100], not $ elem x sieve]
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97]
```

This is still very slow, for any number much above even 1000 (where you'd use 500 and 250). Then again, why the 25 (250) limit? Your code follows the

```
primes = [x| x<-[2..], not $ elem x 
                       [y*z| y<-[2..x`div`2], z<-[2..min y (x`div`y)]]]
```

idea, i.e. `y*z = 2*y .. min (y*y) x`, so with the known top limit (`x <= n`) it should be

```
primesTo n = [x| let sieve=[y*z| y<-[2..n`div`2], z<-[2..min y (n`div`y)]],
                 x<-[2..n], not $ elem x sieve]
```

(incidentally, `max (min y (n/y)) {y=2..n/2} = sqrt n`, so we could've used 10 instead of 25, (and 31 instead of 250, for the 1000)).

Now 1000 is not a problem, only above ~ 10,000 we again begin to see that it's slow (still), running at *n<sup>2.05..2.10</sup>* [empirical orders of growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) (quick testing interpreted code in GHCi at *n = 5000, 10000, 15000*).

---

As for your second (now deleted) function, it can be rewritten, step by step improving its speed, as

```
isPrime n = length [x | x<-[2..n], n `mod` x == 0] == 1
          = take 1 [x | x<-[2..n], n `mod` x == 0] == [n]
          = [x | x<- takeWhile ((<=n).(^2)) [2..n], n `mod` x == 0] == []
          = and [n `mod` x > 0 | x<- takeWhile ((<=n).(^2)) (2:[3,5..n])]
```

now, compiled, it can get first 10,000 primes in few tenths of a second.